# Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

currently trying to find a solution to a problem that's hurting my app right now. I'm wanting to see if i can change the following code to require less memory. Right now, i have five methods which all do the following,

```
-(void)createObstacle0 {
  int yMin = (CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)+190);
  int yMax = (CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)+270);
  CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(-20, yMin + arc4random_uniform(yMax - yMin));

  SKSpriteNode *obstacle = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"obstacle"];
  obstacle.position = CGPointMake(startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
  obstacle.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:21.5];
  obstacle.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = enemyCategory;
  obstacle.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = playerCategory;
  obstacle.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
  obstacle.name = @"obstacle0";
  [self addChild:obstacle];

  [obstacle runAction:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(340, startPoint.y) duration:minTime + arc4random_uniform(maxTime - minTime)]];
  float randomNum = arc4random_uniform(3.0) + 0.1;
  [self performSelector:@selector(createObstacle0) withObject:nil afterDelay:randomNum];
}
```

I tried declaring a SKSpriteNode in my .h file and have each method use that instead of the SKSpriteNode declared inside of them, but i get the above error. Can somebody show me how i can change my code so the image "obstacle" is only loaded once.

Answer (score 0):

From the bit of code you posted it appears you are running an unending loop for creating the obstacle object.

Try removing the code line `[self performSelector:@selector(createObstacle0) withObject:nil afterDelay:randomNum];`

Add a timer function like this:

```
- (void)startTimer
{
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(timerAction)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
}

-(void)timerAction
{
    NSLog(@"do something");
}
```

You can start the `startTimer` method by calling it like this `[self startTimer];`

You can do this from either your init method or anywhere else you need to.

Comment: Yes i know, objects keep on spawning until the player hits one of them and the scene transitions, that's intentional.

Comment: @user3552678 - Did it work after you removed the line?

Comment: It works, no crash or anything, but my game has lots of objects coming form the side, without that line, they won't continue to come,only one will.

Comment: @user3552678 - I have amended the code sample to include a timer for you to use to replace the one you removed.

Comment: how does this differ from what i have? And when i try to run more than one of them, it runs hundreds of times

Comment: It is different that it does not cause your code to crash. Second, I do not know the rest of your code so I can't comment on "it runs hundreds of times". If you need to change the timer speed change 1 to whatever you need. If you need to cancel the timer, create a reference to it and use [myTimerName invalidate];

Comment: can i have more than one timer i should of said. When i do, even if the time interval is 1, it will run the method very,very quickly, making hundred's of nodes

Comment: You can have as many timers as you want. As I said earlier, if the time interval is too fast, change the 1 to something higher. BTW, the time interval is in seconds. So 1 = 1 second.

Comment: ok i got them spawning correctly now, i just had arc4random in the wrong place. Another question, this isn't loading the image only once, is it? Because SKSpriteNode *obstacle = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"obstacle"]; still seems to be loading way to many times, its taking so much memory.

Comment: Use a texture atlas. That will decrease the amount of memory your sprites will use.

Answer (score 0):

Here's possibly a bit more "SpriteKit" like answer. You could also put a bulk of the creation process into a block in a background thread, and then do the add and actions in a main thread, depending on how intense other things were in your app. The key thing with the example below would be that it's using actions, and that the sequence has a key.

```
-(void)createObstacleRepeatingMethod {

int yMin = (CGRectGetMidY(thingShowingObstacles.frame)+190);
int yMax = (CGRectGetMidY(thingShowingObstacles.frame)+270);

CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(-20, yMin + arc4random_uniform(yMax - yMin));
SKSpriteNode *obstacle = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"obstacle"];

obstacle.position = CGPointMake(startPoint.x, startPoint.y);

obstacle.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:21.5];
obstacle.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = obstacleCategory;
obstacle.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = playerCategory;
obstacle.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
obstacle.name = @"obstacle0";

[thingShowingObstacles addChild:obstacle];
[obstacle runAction:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(340, startPoint.y) duration:minTime + arc4random_uniform(maxTime - minTime)]];

SKAction *waitAction = [SKAction waitForDuration:1.5 withRange:1.4];
SKAction *callCreateObstacleAgain = [SKAction runBlock:^{
    [thingShowingObstacles createObstacleRepeatingMethod];
}];

SKAction *theSequenceForWaitThenCall = [SKAction sequence:@[waitAction, callCreateObstacleAgain]];

[thingShowingObstacles runAction:theSequenceForWaitThenCall withKey:@"createObstacleSequence"];

//the sequence having a key also ensures that there will only ever be one of the sequence actions running
//it also ensures that you have fine grained control over removing the action by calling
[thingShowingObstacles removeActionForKey:@"createObstacleSequence"]; }
```